# KitchenSink tools/apkbuilder error when trying to run for Android

Tags: android, titanium

When I run KitchenSink example project on iPhone emulator everything is OK, but trying to launch for Android emulator produces errors:

```
[ERROR] /Users/lukasz/Android/android-sdk-mac_x86/tools/apkbuilder
[ERROR] Failed installing com.appcelerator.kitchensink: pkg: /data/local/tmp/app.apk
```

It happens whatever Androig API I choose (from 1.5 to 2.2 or from APIs 1.5 to APIs 2.2).
I am using Titanium Developer 1.2.1, titanium SDK 1.4.1.11

Where is the problem?

As far as I can see Android SDKs and platforms work correctly because I can successfully compile Android projects from diffrent IDE (Netbeans).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had this error trying to deploy to android sdk version 2.3.

I found this article;
http://developer.appcelerator.com/question/51051/failed-installing-comappceleratorkitchensink-pkg-datalocaltmpappapk

Initially I tried setting the sdk in the build screen to 2.2 but that still errored. However, **once I selected "APIs 2.2" it installed fine.**

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problems with Appcelerator. Try running Android emulator from console before you start the app in Appcelerator.

Comment: Strange as I get emulator: command not found, or android: command not found even when I am trying to fire them from the tools directory. It gers even stranger when Android emulator is launched automatically by NetBeans IDE just by running project.

Answer (score 0):

The fix is to go into the Android SDK Manager and install "Android 3.0 (API 11)". Make sure the app uses emulator "Google APIs (Android 2.3.3)" and "WVGA854". I assume there's a Titanium bug because you have to install a higher API level (3.0) than is actually used (2.3.3). Using exactly these settings, Kitchen Sink works as expected.